# How to use CFA in R to justify averiging of Likert scale and further calculation

Tags: r, anova, ordinal-data, likert, confirmatory-factor

I am currently writing a paper for school and currently have 3 sections of questionnaire questions based on the Likert scale, where each section has 4 questions that I need to group together. Further, I need to use ordinal logistic regression and using averaged Likert scale as the dependent variable and treatment (factor) as the independent. My Professor asked me to do CFA, to justify that all questions are equally present in the averaging results.

So far, I did CFA with the general concept to prove that every 4 questions measure the same concept (ability =~ q1+q2+q3+q4). However, I am not sure how to move further. Whether, this justifies the averaging, whether I could use the latent factors computed by CFA further (eg. doing ANOVA), whether there is a possibility to add the treatments to this model,  or what exactly the correct approach should be. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The factor score won't be ordinal, thus ordinal regression is not applicable to them. Furthermore, even the averaged scores will be hard to use in an ordinal logistic regression since the number of categories may be too. The most reasonably practical solution I see is to model the factor scores (or averaged scores if you really believe your latent scores are better than CFA) using classical regression.

Comment: So far I used rounding for the factor score, however, I know this approach is very tricky. In general, what do you believe to be the most meaningful approach? Additionally, can I use the latent variables computed in CFA to run ANOVA and use them as a dependant variable? There are also differing views on this.

Comment: The factor scores have the advantage of being linear combinations (just as the one you would build yourself through means) but with weight objectively determined from the data and subject to a given optimality criteria (i.e. maximise total variability). Thus I find the use of factor scores for post-FA far more meaningful than the use of the arbitrary sum of items.

Comment: CFA allows you to fit and compare the fit of different models. For example, if a model with an equality constrain for the factor loadings and an equality constraint to the error variances fits the data well, then the items are saif to be parallel and the sum score of the items is a good estimate of the latent trait score of a person. See the book by Raykov and Marcoulides (https://www.routledge.com/Introduction-to-Psychometric-Theory/Raykov-Marcoulides/p/book/9780415878227)